# nesting a custom component that contains a mat-autocomplete in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having some trouble figuring out how to go about adding a nested component to the parent form group when this component has just a mat-autocomplete. I have tried the same approach with the one used for the address subform which works fine, however for the user search I need to pass in the entire user because that is what the autocomplete expects as well as binds to - so this has turned quite ugly:

1. I had to use userFormGroup: { user: client?.Agent || '' }
2. In writeValue below I have some ugly logic where sometimes the value is my actual object, but other times when updates come from the parent form, I have to use val.user to bind to the formgroup.

Here are parts of the files involved:

**client-information.component.ts** declare a formgroup

```
    this.clientFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      address: [],
      userFormGroup: [],
    });

this.clientFormGroup.setValue({
      firstName: client?.Contact?.FirstName || '',
      lastName: client?.Contact?.LastName || '',
      address: client?.Contact?.Address || '',
      userFormGroup: { user: client?.User || '' },
    });
```

Next we have the **client-information.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="clientFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="save($event)" #clientForm="ngForm" novalidate>

   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
         <input matInput type="text" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name (required)">
      <mat-error *ngIf="clientFormGroup.get('firstName').hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <app-address formControlName="address"></app-address>

    <app-user-search formControlName="userFormGroup"></app-user-search>
</form>
```

**user-search.component.ts**

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex>
    <mat-label>Agent</mat-label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="user" matInput placeholder="Search Agent" [matAutocomplete]="userSearch">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption [displayWith]="displayUserFn" #userSearch="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users$ | async" [value]="user">
        {{ user.Contact.FirstName }} {{ user.Contact.LastName }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

**user-search.component.html**

```
export class UserSearchComponent
  implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  userFormGroup: FormGroup;

  users$: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createUserFormGroup();
  }

  private createUserFormGroup() {
    this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      user: ['', [Validators.required], [this.validateUser()]],
    });
  }

  private resetUserFormGroup(user: User, emitEvent = true) {
    this.userFormGroup.setValue(
      {
        user,
      },
      { emitEvent }
    );
  }
..............
writeValue(val: any): void {
     if (val && val.user) {
      this.resetUserFormGroup(val.user, false);
    } else if (val) {
      this.resetUserFormGroup(val, false);
    } else {
      this.userFormGroup.reset();
    }
  }
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parent formGroup reference via property binding.

```
 <app-user-search [parentForm]="clientFormGroup"></app-user-search>
```

in user-search.component.ts get that object with @Input() decorator and modify it however you want. In this way only 1 object is created.

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer not to do this.